# Qt and Qss: How to make text in slider box and non-label text bigger?

Tags: qt, font-size, qtstylesheets

I'm working with Qt and I'm wanting to make all text in my widget larger. I've been successful with labels, but I also need to increase font size of the text in boxes or text that isn't tagged as a label.

Below is a picture of my widget. You'll notice the "3.2m/s", "60%", and "Modules" text is a lot smaller than everything else. Is there any way to make those bigger? I'm not sure what classes refer to those things (I'm not sure if there even are any such classes)

Picture of full widget:

[image: The full widget. I'm trying to make the "Modules" and "3.2m/s" and "60%" text bigger]

I'm wanting to make these three things bigger:

[image: How do I make this text bigger?]

[image: How do I make this text bigger?]

[image: How do I make this text bigger?]

Again, I haven't been able to find any class names that reference these text, so I'm not sure how to enlarge it. I'd appreciate any ideas whatsoever, and I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: Do you want to make the whole widget bigger or just the font?

Comment: @Cendolt Just the font, but I'd imagine the window would need to get bigger to accommodate the font (the font shouldn't leave the window). Thank you for the response by the way, appreciate it!